# Mysql query - faster?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have this MySQL query, and as I have lots of records this gets very slow, the computers that use the software (cash registers) aren't that powerful either.
Is there a way to get the same result, but faster? Would really appreciate help!

```
SELECT d.sifra, COUNT(d.sifra) AS pogosti, c.*, s.Stevilka as Stev_sk FROM Cenik c, dnevna d, Podskupina s 
WHERE d.sifra = c.Sifra AND d.datum >= DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 DAY))
GROUP BY d.sifra ORDER BY pogosti DESC limit 27
```

Comment: What's the point of doing a cross join with s? You could not cross join and just multiply by the number of rows in s and you get the same count.

Comment: To get some more concrete answers, please provide the definitions of the tables involved, and some relevant sample data.

Comment: Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause; *always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried **indexing**?

You are using c.Sifra in the WHERE, so you probably want

```
CREATE INDEX Cenik_Sifra ON Cenik(Sifra);
```

Also you use datum and sifra from dnevna, and datum is your SELECT, so

```
CREATE INDEX dnevna_ndx ON dnevna(datum, sifra);
```

Finally there's no JOIN condition on Podskupina, whence you draw Stevilka. Is this a constant table? As it is, you're just counting rows in Podskupina and/or getting an unspecified value out of it, unless it only has the one row.

On some versions of MySQL you might also find benefit in pre-calculating the datum:

```
SELECT @datum := DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 DAY))
```

and then use @datum in your query. This might improve its chances of a good indexed performance.

Without knowing more about the structure and cardinality of the involved tables, though, there's little that can be done.

At the very least you should post the result of

```
EXPLAIN SELECT...(your select)
```

in the question.

Comment: i dont know how i missed this, but already precalculating the date, like you said, made a huge difference! its now fast enough!
the problem is the query is used in a loop that populates buttons, which made it ultra-slow.. but now its all good thanks to you.
anyway, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

you don't have condition to join Podskupina s, and you get cross join (all to all), so you get x rows from join "d.sifra = c.Sifra" multiplicate by y rows of Podskupina s

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a very problematic query. Do you really need to return all of c.* ?  And where's the join or filter on Podskupina? Once you tighten the query, make sure you've created good indexes on the tables. For example, presuming you've already got a clustered index on a unique ID as a primary key in dnevna, performance would typically benefit by putting a secondary index on the sifra and datum columns.